# Flutter nesting Draggable widget inside DragTarget widget

Tags: flutter

How can i make it such that a user can drag an exercise from one instance of a workout to another. If the current solution cant work, what is the best alternative?

This is my current code.

```
DragTarget(
   builder:(BuildContext context, candidateData, rejectedData){
      return ReoderableListView(
         children: workoutItems.asMap().entries.map((element){
            return Dismissible(
                key: ValueKey('${element.key}'),
                direction:,
                confirmDismiss:(){},
                child : Container(
                   child: ReoderableListView(
                    children : exercises.asMap().entries.map((e) {
                       return Draggable(
                          child: Dismissible(
                           child: Text('Exercise')
                          );
                       );
                    }
                   )
                ),
             );
         }).toList()
      );
   }
)
```